# Changing SATA Mode from RST to AHCI, impact on TRIM?

Tags: 20.04, ssd, trim, rst

So, I've bought a laptop, and I have windows installed on the SSD and I wanna install Ubuntu 20.04 on the HDD.

The Linux installer presented an error "This computer uses Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology). You need to turn off RST before installing Ubuntu."
And suggested to check: https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/ for more information.

Ok, did some research and I have to change the SATA Mode

1. ***from:*** RST Premium with Optane (current) ***to:*** AHCI

That's fine since I dont have any Optane memory, nor use RAID.

However, one thing kinda scared me...

**On the Ubuntu's webpage FAQ there is this statement:**

> *" The change from RST to AHCI may result in the loss of some of the advanced functionality that the RST module offers (for instance TRIM
> for SSD)."*

Wait, what? So my SSD no longer will use TRIM?
I mean, beyond the safety problems, "TRIM" is necessary to increase the life span of the SSD, right?

Am I missing something? hehehehe
If I disable intel RST, my computer is no longer doing any sort of TRIM?

Thank you!

Comment: I do not have Intel RST nor Optane and am using AHCI. Trim has worked on my SSDs. Orginally I used my own script, but now it is all automatic. If worried after you install, check when it is supposed to run & manually run trim afterwards and it then should show very little trim. `systemctl status fstrim.timer`

Comment: Windows will give a hissy fit if you just change RST to ACHI.  Must adjust Windows first so it will boot after(google how).  If you don't want or need Windows, have read that Ubuntu will use/install on RST system if it is the only OS, not dual boot.